# I want to program the graphic UI program for Ubuntu...What is the starting point?

Tags: gui, programming

Hello I am a C++ Programmer for windows for many years..
Nowadays I need to code GUI program for Ubuntu or possibly for all linux machines...
but I don't have any clue for starting with..
Qt is one solution but I want to talk with directly the desktop of Ubuntu...

Please where should I start from....as I know, Qt desktop and KDE desktop was the environment before...

Answer (score 0):

The big GUI toolkits on Linux are [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) as used by e.g. KDE and [GTK](http://www.gtkmm.org/) as used by e.g. GNOME. Both can be used with desktops that are based on the other one but  the programs will feel less good integrated and there may be some glitches when using them.

In addition to this most desktop environments provide some own APIs which give you enhanced functionality and integration for this one desktop but usually at the price of less compatibility with other desktops.

So the first step is to decide what your target environments are. Usually there are some developer resources at the desktop`s web site (e.g. [KDE](https://techbase.kde.org), [GNOME](https://developer.gnome.org/)) to help you getting started.